# storage account static website gives other values in Firefox as in IE and chrome

Tags: html, css, azure, azure-storage-account

I have created a simple index.html file.In my storage account I have enabled the function statistic websites.When I paste this index.html file inside the $web container I can navigate to the file by
1. using the endpoint URL with the name of the file as index.
2. or by using the endpoint URL by typing the name of the file after the /

1. the URL of my static website :  https://storaccount.z6.web.core.windows.net/
2. The URL I use to access the file  https://storaccount.z6.web.core.windows.net/index.html
   Now comes the strange part.In Firefox I have the  tag only inplemented when I use the url with the filename specified (2). even  if I specify in azure portal that index.html is the index page.In Chrome neither the url or the url + filename have the  tag implementedIn IE they both work. The URL and the URL + filename
   To give a little context:

```html
HTML  file:
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <style> TABLE {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;} TH {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; background-color: #6495ED;} TD {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;} </style> </head><body> <table> <colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup> <tr><th>Date</th><th>Vm</th><th>ResourceGroup</th><th>Event Initiated By</th><th>Subscription Name</th></tr> <tr><td>16/04/2019</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>-</td></tr> <tr><td>16/04/2019</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>-</td></tr> <tr><td>09/04/2019</td><td>--</td><td>-</td><td></td><td>-</td></tr> <tr><td>26/04/2019</td><td></td><td></td><td>.</td><td>-</td></tr> <tr><td>15/04/2019</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>-</td></tr> <tr><td>26/04/2019</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr> <tr><td>29/04/2019</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>-</td></tr> <tr><td>08/04/2019</td><td>-</td><td></td><td></td><td>-</td></tr> </table> </body></html>
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Is this my fault. That I didn't mention the style tag in the html file properly ?
Is this a bug (read feature) of Azure ?

This is firefox: because Chrome gives Picture 1 with both URLs and IE gives picture 2 with both URLs

Comment: More than likely the issue is with `Content-Type` property of your `Report.html` file. In my experience IE is somewhat more smarter than Chrome in dealing with content where content-type property is not defined. Please change the content-type property of the blob to `text/html` and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: This totally did the trick. 
If you convert your comment to an answer I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, please check the `Content-Type` property of `Report.html` blob. In my experience, IE is somewhat more smarter in rendering content when content-type property is not defined.

To fix the problem, please change the `Content-Type` property of the blob to `text/html` and you should see it rendered properly in Chrome as well.